# Add dropdown that dynamically change in Wordpress custom post type admin form

Tags: wordpress, dropdown, custom-post-type

I need to create a custom post type in Wordpress that has a field called "code". Let's call this CPT "city-code". Each code is associated with a city. This association is represented by JSON as follows:

```
{
  cities: [
    {
     name: "New York",
     codes: [1,2,3]
    }
    ...
  ]
}
```

I don't want to make the user input the code manually when creating a post in the admin area. To avoid this issue, I want to implement two dropdowns. The first dropdown has a list of cities. When the user selects a city, a list of codes related to that city should be enabled in the second dropdown. For example, if the user selects "New York", the second dropdown will enable the user to select 1, 2, or 3 codes.

I have no questions about implementing dropdown dynamics.

The question is: how can I add these custom dropdowns in CPT add/editing area?

I've tried [Advanced Custom Fields Pro](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/) plugin, but this not offers customizable options that meet my needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To handle this issue, I first used [custom metabox](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/metadata/custom-meta-boxes/) to generate two custom fields: one for the city, other for the code.

In each custom field, I defined a unique class that could be handled by a javascript script. Then, I write a Jquery script that handles the `change` event on the first field. When a user changes it, then I just rewrite the options list in the second field using Jquery.

Finally, I just loaded the fields on the area I want.

Using this approach, WordPress stores both values (city and code) as post meta. It could be get using `get_post_meta` function.